# Use of Calender.LONG in getDisplayNames() unresolved

Tags: android, calendar

I am trying to use `getDisplayNames()` on a Calendar object in my Android code.  I have `java.util.Calendar` included and haven't had any troubles using any other public members of the Calendar class (i.e. Calendar.MONTH).  Now I am attempting the following line...

```
mReminderCal.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.US)
```

And Eclipse is telling me `Calendar.LONG` or `Calendar.SHORT` don't exist.

According to the documentation here they should exist: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#LONG

Any insight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the issue.

The `getDisplayName()` and associated `Calendar.LONG` and `Calendar.SHORT` are API level 9 only.  I'm on API level 4 for backwards compatibility.  I suppose, I will have to create my own function to translate the month enums into strings.

Comment: Whats a way to do it for api above level 9?

Answer (score 6):

Try This (same for Gregorian or regular calendar).  DateFormatSymbols is API level 1.

```
int month = date.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH);  
String monthName = new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[month];
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
mReminderCal.getDisplayName(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, java.util.Calendar.LONG, Locale.US);
```

or static imports:

```
import static java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH;
```

It seems that you have already imported android's `Calendar` class, and in your line you try to get the fields from that class. So, you need to tell compiler explicitly what exact `Calendar` you use.

Comment: I tried both directly using `java.util.Calendar.LONG` but it is still claiming the LONG portion is unresolved.

Comment: are you sure you have jdk 6 bounded to your project?

Comment: I figured it out.  It was an API Level issue.  sorry to bother.  +1 for helpin me out though!